# Reordering data and making a re-ordered list in r

Tags: r, sorting, levels

I previously asked this question:"

How do I re-order a dataframe with multiple species in r. Each species has a different number of observations and I need the final dataframe to be ordered in descending order with the species with most observations listed first. In this example the final dataframe should look list specie B first then Species C and finally specie A."

```
colA= c("C","C","C","B","B","B","B","A","A")
colB= c(1.1,2.1,3.1,4.1,5.1,6.1,7.1,8.1,9.1)
colC= c(-1.2,-2.1,-3.1,-4.1,-5.1,-6.1,-7.1,-8.1,-9.1)
df= data.frame (spp=colA, latitude=colB, longitude=colC)
df
```

I received a great answer which worked well:

```
# add a column counting the number of rows in each species
df <- transform(df, n  = ave(latitude ,spp, FUN = length))
# order by this new column
dfordered <- df[order(df$n),decreasing = TRUE]
```

but now I am stuck again in making an object"species" which has the ordered species names in it. 
Right now I have:

```
species <- levels(df$spp)
```

this command puts everything back in alphabetical order but I need the object to be ordered by "n" (the number of records). Any suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Cheers, 
Israel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as easy as using `unique`. I coerce to `character` so as not to get confused between levels and actual values.

```
 unique(as.character(dfordered$spp))
```

To get here from the original data, use `table`

```
table(df$spp)

##  A B C 
##  2 4 3
```

You can sort this

```
sppCount <- table(df$spp)

names(sort(sppCount, decreasing = TRUE))

# [1] "B" "C" "A"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are primarily interested in relative abundance, you may also want your `spp` factor to be ordered by frequency. In that case, use `reorder()` to arrange its levels as desired, and then sort the data.frame so that the species with the most observations come first.

```
df <- transform(df, spp = reorder(spp, spp, length))
df[order(df$spp, decreasing=TRUE),]
#   spp latitude longitude
# 4   B      4.1      -4.1
# 5   B      5.1      -5.1
# 6   B      6.1      -6.1
# 7   B      7.1      -7.1
# 1   C      1.1      -1.2
# 2   C      2.1      -2.1
# 3   C      3.1      -3.1
# 8   A      8.1      -8.1
# 9   A      9.1      -9.1

## To see one advantage of reordering the factor levels
barplot(table(df$spp))
```